# Divine Name of Ehy-eh Asher Ehy-eh

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, yetziat-mitzrayim, divine-names

[Shemot 3:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.3.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaks about one of the name of Hashem called Eh-yeh Asher Eh-yeh.

How does this name go along with the redemtion from egypt? Why specifically this name is used?

Comment: וַיֹּ֤אמֶר מֹשֶׁה֙ אֶל־הָ֣אֱלֹהִ֔ים מִ֣י אָנֹ֔כִי כִּ֥י אֵלֵ֖ךְ אֶל־פַּרְעֹ֑ה וְכִ֥י אוֹצִ֛יא אֶת־בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל מִמִּצְרָֽיִם׃
וַיֹּ֙אמֶר֙ **כִּֽי־אֶֽהְיֶ֣ה עִמָּ֔ךְ** וְזֶה־לְּךָ֣ הָא֔וֹת כִּ֥י אָנֹכִ֖י שְׁלַחְתִּ֑יךָ בְּהוֹצִֽיאֲךָ֤ אֶת־הָעָם֙ מִמִּצְרַ֔יִם תַּֽעַבְדוּן֙ אֶת־הָ֣אֱלֹהִ֔ים עַ֖ל הָהָ֥ר הַזֶּֽה׃

Answer (score 3):

[Berachot 9b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.9b.6?lang=bi):

> אהיה אשר אהיה אמר לו הקדוש ברוך הוא למשה לך אמור להם לישראל אני הייתי עמכם בשעבוד זה ואני אהיה עמכם בשעבוד מלכיות
>
> [The name] Eh-yeh Asher Eh-yeh (lit. I will be that I will be): Said the Holy One (Blessed be He) to Moshe, “Go tell Israel, ‘I was with you in this enslavement, and I will be with you in the enslavements of the kingdoms [in the future]’”.

This approach is also quoted by [Rashi to Shemot 3:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Exodus.3.14.1?lang=bi).

Comment: This quote from Berachot doesn't really answer what is being asked. It's only giving a slight insight into what that particular name relates to. You really need to be addressing Shemot 3:13-16. Each one of these 4 posukim provides the answer to this question fully.

Comment: Can you please post it

Comment: @RhHaokip If your comment was addressed at YaacovDeane you need to include his name, otherwise he may not see it

Comment: @YaacovDeane ^^^^